# Pandas drop rows where the difference hasn't reached a threshold

Tags: python, pandas

So let's say we have a table like this, (time, distance, velocity, change in distance, in meters and seconds):

```
   t    d    v  delta_d
0  0  1.0  0.5      NaN
1  1  1.5  0.1      0.5
2  2  1.6  0.1      0.1
3  3  1.7  0.0      0.1
4  4  1.7  0.1      0.0
5  5  1.8  0.1      0.1
6  6  1.9  0.6      0.1
7  7  2.5  0.7      0.6
8  8  3.2  0.7      0.7
```

How do i drop the rows where the total delta_d hasn't changed by a certain amount?

i.e. If I were iterating over the rows, how would I drop points in between segments of n meters?
essentially "resampling" based on distance, but without interpolation?

Let's say I only want a reading at least every 0.15 meters, but I don't want to just drop points less than 0.15m...

I could do this with a for loop and a counter, and drop unless I hit my threshold, but is there a pandas way to do it?

edit: My expected output would be something like this:

```
   t    d    v  delta_d
0  0  1.0  0.5      NaN
1  1  1.5  0.1      0.5
3  3  1.7  0.0      0.1
6  6  1.9  0.6      0.1
7  7  2.5  0.7      0.6
```

Comment: Accumulated change, or say either positive or negative change? Also could you share the expected output?

Comment: What is your expected outcome for the example above?

Comment: accumulated change

Comment: I don't understand the output, can you be more precise on your decision rule ? Why the 6th rows is removed while the 5th isn't ?

Comment: Same goes for row 8, where the diff is 0.1. If I understand you correctly, only row 0, 1 and 7 should remain.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my own expected output, I fixed it now.
The cumulative small increments push the threshold over the 1.5 limit. I don't want to lose all data points lower than a certain amount, I just want to reduce the frequency of low change data points based on on a threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understand your question correctly,
to find out different value per row you can use [pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 10]})
df['diff']=df.diff()
```

it will give you, something like

[image]

After that you can just filter out the difference based on your number

```
df[df['diff']>=1]
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I am looking for.
I do not want to lose all points below a certain diff, I want to reduce the frequency of those under a certain diff based on a cumulative threshold

Comment: @Kyle did you find a performant solution (without iteration)?

Comment: Back in 2019, I did not understand what this answer was actually doing. Upon reading it again, it does in fact answer the question. It is taking a diff to find the amount that each value is changing by, and after that, we can use the df[df['diff]>x] to filter out those under the threshold. So in fact, this answer is correct. Unfortunately, I do not remember where or how I solved this problem otherwise.